# PartialView redirects rather than inserts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a form and a partial view on my razor page, the idea being that if I change the dropdownlist, the Controller does some work and sets a ViewBag.ShowAlert (bool) that triggers the partial view to be displayed.

While this works, instead of just showing the code within the partial view, the partial view shows as a new view rather than on the same view.

Any idea why?

The view looks like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AlterVote", "ChangeVoteType"))  
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h1>New voting preference</h1>
    <hr />

    <p>Please select the type of vote you wish to change to @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SelectedType, ViewBag.myList as SelectList, "Voting type", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();"})</p>

    <div id="partialDiv">
        @if (ViewBag.ShowAlert)
        {
            @Html.Partial("VotingChange")
        }
    </div>
</div>
}
```

The controller handling the HttpPost is this

```
[HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult AlterVote(Dropdown dropType)
    {
        ChangeBoilerPlate(dropType.SelectedType);
        dropType.CurrentType = VoteTypeNames[(int)HomeController.VoterModel.CurrentVoteType];
        return PartialView("VotingChange", dropType);
    }
```

I'm guessing that this is down to the initial view being a form, so the partial gets confused as to where to insert the view.

Comment: `onchange = "this.form.submit();"` this triggers a form submission and the subsequent navigation (the new view). You need to trigger an AJAX request and handle the response to update the page element `#partialDiv`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, by `the partial view shows as a new view` you mean it comes with a `html` tag, `body` and the full layout again. To solve this, you need to set up the layout to `null` inside your partial view, like so:

```
@model YourNamespace.Dropdown

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!-- partial view html below -->
<div>
</div>
```

> The div tag is just to illustrate.

While this might solve your problem, you might want to load the partial view without reloading the whole page again. This is possible using ajax, like so:

**Main View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AlterVote", "ChangeVoteType"))  
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h1>New voting preference</h1>
    <hr />

    <p>Please select the type of vote you wish to change to @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SelectedType, ViewBag.myList as SelectList, "Voting type", new { id = "vote"})</p>

    <div id="partialDiv">
    </div>
</div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#vote').change(function() {
        var selectedType = $(this).val();
        $.post('yourserver/YourController/AlterVote', { "SelectedType": selectedType })
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#partialDiv').html(data);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            console.log('Whoops, something went wrong!!!');
        });
    });
  });
</script>
```

So I just added a javascript to listen to that same change event on your dropdrown, but instead of submitting the form, I just use ajax to load the partial view html without reloading the entire page.

Just fix the URL and remember to set up layout to `null` in your partial view. Also, you might want this javascript in a separate file, thus loading it with bundles.

Comment: That's a cool answer - thanks. Problem I'm getting now though is ChangeVoteTypeController/AlterVote is giving a 404 (it is sitting on the root of the server, so the full [testing] url is 127.0.0.1:8080/ChangeVoteTypeController/AlterVote. AlterVote is set as [HttpPost] within the controller

Comment: @Nodoid since it's `HttpPost`, you can't just open the url in browser, so the expected behavior from asp.net mvc is to deliver a 404, since it won't find a get action at all. You either change your action to `HttpGet` temporarily (you can also remove the `Dropdown` parameter and use a fixed value just for testing), then check with browser. Then you change it again to `HttpPost` (put parameter again) and test the javascript method. If it's the same server, you can just set `/ChangeVoteTypeController/AlterVote` as url and check the browser's console for errors.